# Regarding the 2016 Community Moderator Election Candidate Score

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, election

I was considering nominating myself as a candidate but I figure my candidate score is probably too low to throw my hat in the ring at this time.

Is there a way to find out what my candidate score is before nominating myself?

---

Thank you @AndreSilva [for the link](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=72697) (just change userids to your id for your score)

Comment: No,any GIS SE user with a reputation of 300 can nominate themselves. But you will have to be very quick as the Nomination Phase closes in less than 1 hour.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wondered the same thing before I nominated myself.

You can hover your mouse over the existing nominations and see what each score component is...It looks like the n/40 score is based on 4 things:

- 1 point per 1k of reputation, up to 20k rep (so 20 points max)
- Up to 8 points total for each review queue badge (Civic Duty, Deputy, Reviewer, Steward).
- Up to 6 points for each editing badge (Explainer, Organizer, Strunk & White, Tag Editor)
- Up to 6 points for each participation badge (Constituent, Enthusiast, Quorum, Yearling)

But, as Mapperz points out, there's not a minimum score to nominate yourself other than the minimum reputation requirement (300).

Comment: +1. The full list of badges contributing to the candidate score: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election. And a query on SEDE to simulate it: http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=1530814%2C3622940%2C1252759%2C871050%2C572%2C1234256%2C1065190%2C492405%2C616460%2C224988%2C3366929%2C465378%2C229044%2C1380752%2C100297%2C1849664%2C189134%2C542517%2C2371861%2C2581872%2C109702%2C3001736%2C1069068%2C476%2C995926%2C1952862%2C2876565%2C379693%2C1603234.