# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Geographic Information Systems's [fourth moderator election](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Fezter] [image: Midavalo]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4969960354873344/0).

Answer (score 21):

Thanks everyone for your votes. I'm humbled and happy to be joining the company of the existing moderators. I look forward to the task.

Comment: And congratulations to Midavalo. Well deserved.

Answer (score 17):

Congratulations to everyone that voted and nominated themselves for the Election. Condolences to 'Evil Genius' but if it was not for your nomination, the election process could of not made it into the Election Phase.

Comment: Likewise congrats to Fezter and Midavalo and condolences to EvilGenius.  Thanks all for participating in the process.

Comment: There's nothing for me to be disappointed about, as I said before I'm happy with both Fezter and Midavalo as mods. I'm happy that I was able to contribute as I did, and perhaps you'll see me again if the opportunity comes up again!

Answer (score 17):

Yes, many thanks to all who voted, and to @EvilGenius for ensuring there was a vote.  Your turn next time!  And of course congratulations also to @Fezter (who I swear was already a mod!)

Answer (score 8):

This is just an observation that I want to make to try to assist anyone thinking about standing during the next moderator election whenever that might be.

This year the [candidate score (out of 40)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/4) looks like it was a good predictor of the final positions.

If you wish to speculate about how your candidature might have stood up this year, or in preparation for standing at a later election there is an SEDE query that [@AndreSilva found](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4344/regarding-the-2016-community-moderator-election-candidate-score/4345#comment7708_4345) that can [calculate your Candidate Score](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/298418) at any time.

Comment: By far the best predictor in every GIS election has been total reputation.  I believe that statistic alone would have perfectly predicted every outcome.  BTW, to see how current mods stack up on candidate scores, enter "8104, 7424, 79, 276, 64785, 115, 187, 664" for the user IDs in AndreSilva's query.  Note that scores much above 36 are hard for long-time mods to attain, because some badges are awarded for work that only non-mods can do.

Comment: @whuber You're probably right - sensibly I won't try to prove statistically but the two measures seem quite correlated. The perfect score on our site is also prevented by the quiet GIS Chat Room which I think makes the Outspoken badge near unattainable.  I always made gaining rep my  focus and found badges accrued along the way.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the three candidates: it was nice to have election with three good profiles. It was also nice to learn a little bit more about some profiles by reading their answers to "mod-related" questions.

That being said, I am not convinced that the high correlation between rep and probability to be elected is a good sign for the community, because the mods actions are not so much rewarded compared with answering questions. And it doesn't necessarily require the same skills. Last year I was candidate, but with higher rep this year I could "try" some mod actions, and I found it very difficult (I skip one out of five reviews, only duplicates and spams are easy IMHO). Maybe the badges could be a better indicator, but again stating the "mod value" prior to the election doesn't tell everything.

Anyway, congrats to the new mods, they deserve it independently from their rep.